# jQuery slide left and show

Tags: jquery, effects

I extended the `jQuery` effects called `slideRightShow()` and `slideLeftHide()` with a couple functions that work similarly to `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` as seen below.  However, I would also like to implement `slideLeftShow()` and `slideRightHide()`.

I know there are substantial libraries that offer this type of thing (I'd like to avoid adding another large set of `javascript` files), but can anyone provide a simple example of how to implement either `slideLeftShow()` or `slideRightHide()`?

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  slideRightShow: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      jQuery(this).animate({width: 'show'});
    });
  },
  slideLeftHide: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      jQuery(this).animate({width: 'hide'});
    });
  },
  slideRightHide: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      ???
    });
  },
  slideLeftShow: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      ???
    });
  }
});
```

The above `slideRightShow` function starts showing the image from the left side and it progresses toward the right side.  ***I am looking for some way to do the same thing but start from the right side and progress toward the left***.  Thanks!

EDIT

jQuery Interface has something like I need (I basically need their "slide in right" and "slide out left" functions), but I couldn't get this to work with jQuery 1.3: http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/ifx.html .  Also, their demo seems to broken as well as it will only do a slide once before throwing a million errors.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left

Answer (score 186, accepted):

This feature is included as part of jquery ui http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide if you want to extend it with your own names you can use this.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  slideRightShow: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
    });
  },
  slideLeftHide: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
    });
  },
  slideRightHide: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
    });
  },
  slideLeftShow: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
    });
  }
});
```

you will need the following references

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi!  I'm looking for the inverse of what you have implemented there.  Basically, when I use what I have above to show an element, the left part appears first and progresses towards the right.  I am trying to get it to start from the right side and progress towards the left.

Comment: it works if you float the element right.  Otherwise.  you might want to annimate the left property and move the element as you shrink it.

Comment: Changing the element to float "right" didn't reverse the slide for me.  I clarified above if that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I didn't know this was part of the jQuery's effects.  I would give +2 if I could!

Comment: Link of the source of the two ui scripts are now: 
http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js
and
"http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js

Comment: Any idea how you would add callbacks to these solutions (and while you're at it, why not speed too? I am guessing you can't without swapping to use animate() instead.

Comment: And how to do it in case you use jQuery >= 2.0 ?

Answer (score 34):

Don't forget the padding and margins...

```
jQuery.fn.slideLeftHide = function(speed, callback) { 
  this.animate({ 
    width: "hide", 
    paddingLeft: "hide", 
    paddingRight: "hide", 
    marginLeft: "hide", 
    marginRight: "hide" 
  }, speed, callback);
}

jQuery.fn.slideLeftShow = function(speed, callback) { 
  this.animate({ 
    width: "show", 
    paddingLeft: "show", 
    paddingRight: "show", 
    marginLeft: "show", 
    marginRight: "show" 
  }, speed, callback);
}
```

With the speed/callback arguments added, it's a complete drop-in replacement for `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`.

Comment: How can make them to do the same effect with right sliding?

Comment: @JayantVarshney: make sure that the block is right-aligned, possibly with some inner block. This code only shrinks the width. If your CSS can handle that, you'll have a right slide

Comment: Thanks... But I want both the effects on same div.. like opening from right to left and then closing from left to right or vice versa...

Comment: Well then, how about switching classes at the completion callback? :-)

Comment: Thanks, I used CSS3 animations to achieve this functionality

Comment: Great answer. To make it toggle as well, use this: `jQuery.fn.slideLeftToggle = function(speed, callback){
 if(this.is(":visible")){ this.slideLeftHide(speed, callback); }
 else { this.slideLeftShow(speed, callback); }
}`

Answer (score 10):

You can add new function to your jQuery library by adding these line on your own script file and you can easily use `fadeSlideRight()` and `fadeSlideLeft()`.

Note: you can change width of animation as you like instance of 750px.

```
$.fn.fadeSlideRight = function(speed,fn) {
    return $(this).animate({
        'opacity' : 1,
        'width' : '750px'
    },speed || 400, function() {
        $.isFunction(fn) && fn.call(this);
    });
}

$.fn.fadeSlideLeft = function(speed,fn) {
    return $(this).animate({
        'opacity' : 0,
        'width' : '0px'
    },speed || 400,function() {
        $.isFunction(fn) && fn.call(this);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed without including jQuery UI. Just added the opacity and width as parameters. `... = function(opacity, speed, width, fn) {...}`

Answer (score 5):

And if you want to vary the speed and include callbacks simply add them like this :

```
        jQuery.fn.extend({
            slideRightShow: function(speed,callback) {
                return this.each(function() {
                    $(this).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, speed, callback);
                });
            },
            slideLeftHide: function(speed,callback) {
                return this.each(function() {
                    $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, speed, callback);
                });
            },
            slideRightHide: function(speed,callback) {
                return this.each(function() {  
                    $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, speed, callback);
                });
            },
            slideLeftShow: function(speed,callback) {
                return this.each(function() {
                    $(this).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, speed, callback);
                });
            }
        });
```