# Jquery slide from right to left

Tags: jquery

I have the follow code:

```
$("#headerimg" + currentContainer).slideUp(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#headertxt").slideUp(100).css({"display" : "block"});
    animating = false;
  }, 500);
});
```

Now the pictures animate from bottom to top. But i want that the picture, slide from right to left. What in the code i must change?

Comment: you could just animate the right / left margin of your image using 'animate'

Comment: welcome to SO, while you're here please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Can you show a example in this codE?

Answer (score 3):

> **[Here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions)** is a great tutorial to slide
>   elements in different directions.

*from [jQuery - slide right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/jquery-slide-right-to-left)*

Answer (score 1):

There is no build-in method like "`slideLeft`" in jQuery. So you either have to write a little plugin like

```
$.fn.slideLeft = function(speed){
     return this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.animate({'width': '0px'}, jQuery.fx.speeds[speed] || 200);
     });
};
```

or you have to look for an [already existing plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/) out there.