# How can I slide a DIV in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm looking for something in JQuery to allow a synchronized slide of a big div.

The div width can be increased runtime by other jquery functions.

I want to scroll the div horizontally, sliding 50px every second....is it possible to do this synch?

thank you all

Comment: Which direction is it sliding in and which edge do you want to move at 50px per second?

Comment: What do you mean by synchronized here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/596608/106261

Comment: @wheresrhys : horizontally, for example, to the left.

Comment: @Jivings: second and pixel are synch in scroll: 50px each second.

Comment: Synchronized usually refers to something else in JavaScript. You just want a div to slide 50px a second.

Comment: i just want to slide a div synchronized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
(function slide() {
  $('#foo').animate(
    // move 50px to the left
    {left: '-=50px'},

    // in one second
    1000,

    // without easing 
    'linear',

    // recursive call on completion
    slide
  );
}());
```

Comment: does it slide only 50px? i want to slide all the div (for ex 3000px), 50px each second

Comment: @TrustWeb It will slide indefinitely. See the last parameter `slide`.

Comment: oh i see it is recursive...but how do you call this, $("#button").click(slide); ?

Comment: This is just a very basic example of how to have something running indefinitely. If you explain how you will use this, I can help you better.

Comment: thanks a lot.....for example, i would like to stop the slide once it slided all the #foo width.