# Jquery show and slide returns error

Tags: jquery, show, slide, easing

i'm using jquery 1.8.2 and when i do:

```
$(function(){
$(element).show('slide', {direction: 'right'},1000);
});
```

it returns this error:

```
Error: TypeError: p.easing[this.easing] is not a function
File sorgente: http://localhost/js/jquery.js
Line: 2
```

what's happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: p.easing\[this.easing\] is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592279/typeerror-p-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include jQuery UI for the special easing functions

[TypeError: p.easing[this.easing] is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592279/typeerror-p-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function)