# jQuery error: ...easing... is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function
percent, this.options.duration * percent, 0, 1, this.options.duration
```

The code block from jQuery is

```
run: function( percent ) {
    var eased,
    hooks = Tween.propHooks[ this.prop ];
    if ( this.options.duration ) {
         this.pos = eased = jQuery.easing[ this.easing ](
         percent, this.options.duration * percent, 0, 1, this.options.duration
        );
    } 
    ...
```

I attempted to include the jQuery UI (Customized download).
Customized with selecting of "Effects Core" only, Which included easing.

```
 <script src="/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
```

I'm still getting the same ERROR!

Comment: Affecting all browsers? What browser are you testing this under? Also, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592279/typeerror-p-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function apparently due to lack of 'extended' easing functions not included in the bundle.

Comment: have you check using full version of jquery-ui? instead of custom jquery-ui? simply replace with http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: From which code is that called? Can we have a stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this CDN

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js
```

and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try using full version of jquery-ui  or at least double check whether you selected easing option while downloading jquery-ui.

try

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

instead

```
<script src="/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
```

if works then double check with downloaded jquery-ui.