# JQuery slide effect with mouseclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a simple slideshow with JavaScript. I found this link [Page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)
and I want the last slideshow. The slideshow with the header 'scrollRight (click)'. But it doesn't work on my page. The problem is when I press sometimes on the picture, then its away. Here is my page 
[MyPage](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/Ukena/) and here the code:

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    line-height: 20px;
}

body{
    background-image: url(images/hintergrund.png);
}

section{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 1100px;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
 box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

article{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.one{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.two{
    float: right;
    width: 860px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        
        
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.one').cycle({ 
    fx:      'scrollRight', 
    next:   '.one', 
    timeout:  0, 
    easing:  'easeInOutBack' 
});
});
        </script>        
        
        
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <article>
                <div class="one">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="200" height="200" />
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="200" height="200" />
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="200" height="200" />
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="200" height="200" />
                </div>
                <div class="two">
                    <h1>Ansteckbutton</h1>
                    <br>
                    <p>
                    Groesse: 30cm Durchmesser
                    <br>
                    Farbe: Rot
                    <br>
                    Material: Metall
                    <br>
                    Form: Rund
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>
            
            <br>
            <hr>
            <br>
            
            <article>
                                <div class="one">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="two">
                    exampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexamleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexamleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexamleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexamleexample
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>



<!-- article mehrfach verwenden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0z7604z/)**

There is something wrong with the parameters you are providing.

Just try this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.one').cycle();
});
```

Without parameters working fine.

**[Updated Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0z7604z/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.one').cycle({
         fx: 'scrollRight',
         next: '.one',
         timeout: 0
    });
 });
```

**Issue:**
It was issue with applying `easing:  'easeInOutBack'` and it was throwing below error on the console. Removing attribute fixed the issue.

```
TypeError: d.easing[(intermediate value)] is not a function
```

For further investigation of **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592279/typeerror-p-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function)** issue check this stackoverflow answer.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but its not perfect. It should change the image if i click with my mouse on the image.