# Unknown Error - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(this).css("position", "relative");
    $(this).click(function(){
        $("img").animate({top: 500}, 2000, "easeInQuad", function(alert("DONE!");){});
    });
 });
```

This code gives me error `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function`. I don't what is going on.

Comment: `$("document").` ==> `$(document).`

Comment: Include jquery UI. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592279/typeerror-p-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function

Comment: @Tushar It doesn't change anything.

Comment: That may look like it dosn't change anything but it does. If you've included JS in `head` you'll know.

Comment: @irqize use the easing api which provide the easing you are using.

Comment: `function(alert("DONE!");){}` should be `function(){alert("DONE!");}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find two errors.

1) Change

```
$("document")
```

by

```
$(document)
```

2) The attribute is of jqueryui easeInQuad (https://jqueryui.com/easing/). Add the library jqueryui

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error. It must be

```
function() { alert("DONE!"); }
```