# Adding easing on transition throws jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I want to add an easing style into my smooth scrolling code, but whenever I do it throws a constantly increasing jquery error in the console.

```
$('#slider-scrollDown').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollTo-container").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

This is what I have, and I'm trying to add an easing like this:

```
$('#slider-scrollDown').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollTo-container").offset().top
    }, 2000, 'easeInOut');
});
```

The errors I receive in the console are:

> Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Which displays once, and then another below it with an increasing number in red, which doesn't stop.

Comment: remove time delay and write easeInOutCubic

Comment: Okay, but that's not really the kind of easing I want to use...

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592279/typeerror-p-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

It's because easeInOut does not exist... Have a look on this page ;) https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Comment: I get the same error if I use one of the listed examples, such as `easeInOutBack`

Comment: mhhhh... did you try to debug ? If you add a breakpoint where n.easing[this.easing] is done... Which properties are in the n.easing object ?

Comment: got jquery **ui** referenced?

Comment: @BenG Yes, jQuery UI is being loaded and running

Comment: so what do you have in n.easing ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I overlooked something when trying to load easing. I didn't mention that I'm using Wordpress, and I've just discovered that an extra function call is needed to get the jQuery easing functions.

Simply adding `wp_enqueue_script ( 'jquery-effects-core' );` to my list of loads solved the issue.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Alex, why the downvote? Don't be down just because I downvoted your answer, it wasn't helpful!