# How to change fading to easing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hi guys I have the below code and I want to change that fading 'slow' into jquery easing: https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/
But I don't know how to do it, can you help me? I'm starting with javascript and jquery.
thanks in advance, cheers!
`

```
        $("#upClick").click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#scroll').offset().top
            }, 'slow');
        });
```

**Code :**

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="arrowdown">
  <button class="arrow">hi im a dropdow button</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('text').offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeOutExpo');
    // ----------^---- set here
  });
</script>
<div>
  <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of
    human
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of
    human
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of
    human
  </p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of
    human
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, **tutorial**, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: hi, I attach the code below in a new  answer please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `easing` value as 3rd parameter in jQuery [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) method.

```
$("#upClick").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#scroll').offset().top
    }, 'slow','linear');
    // ----------^---- set here
});
```

---

**UPDATE :** Only `swing` and `linear` easing types are works with the jQuery library in order to use other include jQuery UI library. Check the [documentation description of `easing` option](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#easing):

> The remaining parameter of .animate() is a string naming an easing function to use. An easing function specifies the speed at which the animation progresses at different points within the animation. ***The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the [jQuery UI suite](http://jqueryui.com/)***.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!---------^^^^^ include ui library ------------------------------------->
<div class="arrowdown">
  <button class="arrow">hi im a dropdow button</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.text').offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeOutExpo');
    // ----------^---- set here
  });
</script>
<div>
  <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of
    human
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of
    human
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of
    human
  </p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of
    human
  </p>
</div>
```

Refer : [TypeError: p.easing[this.easing] is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592279/typeerror-p-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function)

Comment: for a reason is not working on my website.. look at file:///C:/Users/kenny/Desktop/public_html/index.html there is an arrow below "estilo + elegancia" when I add there the easeOutExpo it doesn't work I dont know why

Comment: @KennyAmaro ___file:///C:/Users/kenny/Desktop/public_html/index.html___  how can I look at your local machine file :)

Comment: @KennyAmaro : you need to include jQuery ui library

Comment: @KennyAmaro : glad to help you