# Conflict Lavalamp Accordion jquery

Tags: jquery, accordion, lavalamp

I cant solve a conflict between  Lavalamp and Accordion, here is the code.
When one of them works, the other does not, and viceversa. 
I have deleted one of the jquery library (jquery-1.4.min.js or jquery.min.js) but it does not work. Also I have change the place of the scripts: The second script works and the first does not. In this particular case, the lavalamp doesnt work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon.yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myriad.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
     $("#one,#two,#three,#four,#five").lavaLamp({
        fx: "backout", 
        speed: 700
     });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

Cufon.replace('li a', {hover: true});

</script>




<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="navAccordion.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //Accordion Nav
    jQuery('.mainNav').navAccordion({
        expandButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>',  //Text inside of buttons can be HTML
        collapseButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>'
    }, 
    function(){
        console.log('Callback')
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any message in the console? (F12 on most browsers)?

Comment: This is the error code:

    TypeError: $(...).lavaLamp is not a function

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put all your external libraries in the beginning. I assume your code is part of the `<head>` in your html-file.-

In addition: Don't load jQuery twice. Use the higher of both versions and put it into the top. My educated guess would be that something like that would work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon.yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myriad.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="navAccordion.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#one,#two,#three,#four,#five").lavaLamp({
        fx: "backout", 
        speed: 700
     });

    //Accordion Nav
    $('.mainNav').navAccordion({
        expandButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>',  //Text inside of buttons can be HTML
        collapseButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>'
    }, 
    function(){
        console.log('Callback')
    });
});
</script>
<body>
Your magic stuff containing something with class mainNav and id "one, two three, four"

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I do what you say, something changes (for better), but the accordion does not works well.
I get this error message:

jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Comment: my best guess would be that this jquery-version does not work with your code. Use the most current version from jquery.com and maybe use jquery UI, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592279/typeerror-p-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function