# Show and hide not working in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery & JqueryUI for first time. I have a `div` named `front`, which I want to display on window load and hide by sliding it after a delay of 5500.
But it's giving errors in jquery.min.js.

The HTML code is `

```
<head>
  <style> 
    #front {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>



<body>
    <div id="front"> </div>

<script>
  function slider() {
    $("#front").show("fade",500);
    $("#front").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:"right"},500);
  }
  window.onload = function () {
    slider();
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t29rh9sL/1/
    and the error message I am getting is

> Uncaught TypeError:     r.easing[this.easing] is not a function
>       at init.run (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at i (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at Function.r.fx.tick (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at eb (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: What's the error? Have you included jqueryui.js in the page? It's a separate file to jquery.js

Comment: "div named front" vs. div with `id="front"`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, you are right I have added CDN link in HTML page. And the error is in jquery.min.js which I have no idea about but on inpecting it shows ---->>> ""                                                                              `jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: r.easing[this.easing] is not a function
    at init.run (jquery.min.js:3)
    at i (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.r.fx.tick (jquery.min.js:3)
    at eb (jquery.min.js:3)`                                      ""

Comment: If you want to use jQuery.UI  include jQuery.js before jQuery.UI

Comment: Ok @swapnilsolanke trying.....but the same happens.

Comment: Given your error this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592279/typeerror-p-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function

Comment: this link will help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592279/typeerror-p-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function

Comment: @Roamer-1888 ` id="front" ` . This ones is what I have used. [[ Not name, but ID is front]]

Comment: @swapnilsolanke the person who asked that question said                                 " Oh i fixed it, i was including both jQuery-min and jQuery on the same file, that was my mistake. Thanx for your help "         **But I have only one js file so that can't be the problem I guess.**

Comment: Is there some version issue ?

Comment: You should do a jsfiddle so people can see where the error is..

Comment: @BorisK Thanks for your suggestion. Jsfiddle .. like a live code right ?                  I have hosted the file here temporarily .                                                                    [link](https://yash140498.000webhostapp.com/)

Comment: @YashYadav Yes, go to https://jsfiddle.net/, click on the gear next to 'javascript' and choose jQuery 3.2.1. Click RUN to test your code, and click SAVE to get a link to share

Comment: We still need your error message.

Comment: @BorisK Ok i visited jsfiddle.net   Here is the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/t29rh9sL/1/) .Thanks Again.

Comment: in your code i see only jquery.min.js file you need to include jquery-ui,js file also.

Comment: @swapnilsolanke Yes it's there i guess it was the order only . Thanks for your a help. It's working now. I created new HTML file and wrote it in the order you told and it works so thank you !

Comment: jQuery UI was missing. I made your code work : https://jsfiddle.net/t29rh9sL/2/ but I cannot answer the question as it is on hold...

Comment: @BorisK , thank you .I had it in original file but in wrong order or maybe at wrong place but works fine now. If anyone answers please mention the order also and I would mark it as correct. Thanks for help guys and sorry for improper formatting. Just joined stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

There is no id name #mainContainer in your code.

You should to place id in body like 
`<body id="mainContainer"><div id="front"> </div></body>`

Comment: I am sorry but that was just typing mistake .The question is solved. I had wrong order of include resource files . Thanks though.