# JQuery .hide and .show not being applied

Tags: javascript, html

Jquery .show and .hide not working. If anybody could help out with this it would be great. I have tried most things but cannot figure out what the error is.

```
<div class="splash-page"
        style="overflow: hidden; display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; align-items: center; height: 100vh; justify-content: center;">
        <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; justify-content: center;">
            <div id="left">
                <img src="" alt="logo">
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <img src="" alt="logo">
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
function flipHomePage() {
    var $ = jQuery;
    $("#left").hide("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 1000);
    $("#right").hide("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000, function () {
        $('.splash-page').hide();
        $('.elementor-container.elementor-column-gap-default').show();
    });
}​
if (jQuery('.page-id-19').length) {
    jQuery('.elementor-container.elementor-column-gap-default').hide();
}
```

Comment: Basically i didn't see any script tags in your code.

Comment: I don't see any element with the id "left" or "right" in your code. Are you using the wrong id's or am I missing something?

Comment: @ShivratnaKumar I have edited this for you

Comment: Have you added the jQuery UI?

Comment: `$('#left').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);` requires the jQuery-ui library. See http://www.jqueryui.com

Comment: Please follow this for more information
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592279/typeerror-p-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the `<script></script>` tags and the `$(function(){ [...] })(jQuery);` to init jQuery lib.
You have to change your Javascript code like this :

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        function flipHomePage()
            $("#left").hide("slide", {
                direction: "left"
            }, 1000);
            $("#right").hide("slide", {
                direction: "right"
            }, 1000, function () {
                $('.splash-page').hide();
                $('.elementor-container.elementor-column-gap-default').show();
            });
        }​
        if ($('.page-id-19').length) {
            $('.elementor-container.elementor-column-gap-default').hide();
        }
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

And of course, you have to include the jQuery script in your `<head></head>` tags