# Fade effect left to right on a image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have fade effect structure. With the following:

```
  <img src='firstStar.jpg' alt='star image' id='firstStar' />

    var loopImages = function(){

         $('#firstStar').fadeIn(1500, function(){

                   $('#firstStar').fadeOut(1500, loopImages);           
         });
    }
    loopImages();
```

It's working. But i want, this effect get left to right. Is it possible?

Comment: You mean it should fade gradually faster on the left side?

Comment: Is it something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this with `animate`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#firstStar").animate({left:200, opacity:"show"}, 1500);
});
```

Make sure the div is initially hidden (style="display:none;").

Answer (score 4):

You can try with this, I used to work with it on my previous project.

http://jonobr1.github.com/diagonalFade/

Hope it fits your needs.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

By 'But i want, this effect get left to right', do you mean to refer this one?

http://www.oik-plugins.com/wordpress-plugins-from-oik-plugins/wordpress-plugins/oik-nivo-slider/nivo-settings/nivo-slider-transition-effects/nivo-slider-effectslicedownright/

If yes, then you can use the effect called as `sliceDownRight`.