# Slide some contents of a page on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am totally new to jQuery and starting out basically so please forgive if this question sounds amateurish or stupid. Any how I want to the header and footer of the page to remain static but the center contents of the page to slide in from the right side when page loads. Here is the page which does exactly that :
[flooring-by-design.com](http://flooring-by-design.com)

I have looked into slide down function of jQuery and animate function but slidedown slides from top-bottom and I don't want that. What should I do?

My content goes like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class='logo'>Site Name</h1>
    <div class='bcontent'>
        <div id="one">One Content</div>
        <div id="two">Two</div>
        <div id="three">Three</div>
    </div>
    <footer>Copy rights</footer>
</div>
```

Div one two and three are the ones which I want to slide in nicely on page load. Just like the example link.

Comment: you could also have a look at [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/)

Comment: I think this question is what you're looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left

Comment: If I understand it properly it is a slider for image and content I don't want slider I only want to animate some content on page load @milkshake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery.

Basically the content is set at an offset of 800px from the left initially using CSS. Then using jQuery `animate`, we slide-in the contents till the offset from left is 0px. You can increase or decrease the duration to alter the speed of the slide-in.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#one").animate({left: "0"}, {
    duration: 2000       
    });
    $("#two").animate({left: "0"}, {
    duration: 2250
    });
    $("#three").animate({left: "0"}, {
    duration: 2500        
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.bcontent > div{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; /* to display the 3 div's in same line */
    height: 200px; /* height, width and border just added for demo, not mandatory */
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    left: 110%; /* Added to avoid the width issue pointed out by DRP96 */
}
.bcontent{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* added to make the content hidden initially and avoid scroll-bar */
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#one").animate({
    left: "0"
  }, {
    duration: 2000
  });
  $("#two").animate({
    left: "0"
  }, {
    duration: 2250
  });
  $("#three").animate({
    left: "0"
  }, {
    duration: 2500
  });
});
```

```css
footer {
  bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.bcontent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bcontent > div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 110%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <h1 class='logo'>Site Name</h1>

  <div class='bcontent'>
    <div id="one" class="span4">One Content</div>
    <div id="two" class="span4">Two</div>
    <div id="three" class="span4">Three</div>
  </div>
  <footer>Copy rights</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: although `left` should be larger than 800.. Maybe 2000, as it would be still visible on larger displays.

Comment: And `$("#one").animate({left: "0"}, { duration: 2000 });` could be simply `$("#one").animate({left: "0"}, 2000);` ;)

Comment: Harry thanks but the problem is that div one two and three are in one line. I am using twitter bootstrap and they are in each column. So I am using <div id="one" class="span4"> so how to use it there?

Comment: @DRP96: Yup, correct on both points. For 1, My jsFiddle window was smaller :D. For 2, I basically wanted to make it obvious as to what the 2000 value is for :)

Comment: @AhmarAli Sorry mate, I didn't quite catch that. Can you update my Fiddle with your HTML structure?

Comment: @Harry here is my page: http://contestlancer.com/davidicus/ where I want to use it

Comment: @Harry for some odd reason it still doesn't work on my webpage. Can you take a look at my page http://contestlancer.com/davidicus/

Comment: @AhmarAli: try to add `style="position:relative; left: 110%;"` to all 3 div tags and check if it works.

Comment: @Harry Can you take a look now at my website. I have added left :110 and also updated the jquery code in footer to my div id's doesn't make a difference

Comment: @Ahmar Ali I still can't see it reflected. In your bootstrap.css file it still shows `left:0` to me. Also, now I don't see the `overflow:hidden` in your row.

Comment: @Harry can you take a look now. When I add overflow:hidden and add left:110% to divs the whole content disappears.

Comment: You are not able to see anything because the `left:110%` is getting applied but for some reason your animate function doesn't seem to be getting executed. I have no idea why :(

Comment: @Harry what is the possible solution then?

Comment: @AhmarAli I copied your code to my local and saw that there were two issues preventing the slide from working. 1. In your bootstrap.css, remove the `left:0;` rule from the declaration for `#portfolio`, `#music` and `#blog`. 2. In your main HTML file add `position:relative; left:110%;` for `span4` (Note: `!important` is not required). These two changes should make it work as I can see it working on my local. Also, the `id` for the second block is wrongly mentioned as `#message` in the script. Change it to `#music`.

Comment: @Harry thanks a lot mate. I can't believe someone at the free forum can work so hard to solve someone else's problem. I really appreciate it and thank you from bottom of my heart. You are wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
<h1 class='logo'>Site Name</h1>

<div class='bcontent'>
<div id="one">One Content</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
 </div>

<footer>Copy rights</footer>

 </div>
```

**for the above html you can refer to the **demo**

Comment: http://contestlancer.com/davidicus/ is where I want to use it. Can you  please take a look and tel me how do I achieve this there this code doesn't work there

Comment: didn't understand what you have commented