# Slide From Right (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code for sliding elements from the left.

```
$(".slide-left")
   .css("margin-left",-$(this).width())
   .delay(400)
   .animate({
       marginLeft:0
 }, 900);
```

However when I try from the right, nothing happens! It seems logical code, what I am clearly missing here?

```
$(".slide-right")
   .css("margin-right",-$(this).width())
   .delay(400)
   .animate({
   marginRight:0
}, 900);
```

Comment: it would be easier to do this by using CSS3 animations and attaching the class with jQuery

Comment: very similar question, having an answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left

Comment: Wouldn't I lose old browser compatibility using the CSS3 animation method though?

Comment: You can use feature detection and write fallback code if you really need to support older browsers.

Comment: please post the css of `slide-right`

Comment: Can you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Using a negative `margin-right` often doesn't work -- it's better to use a positive `margin-left` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give an exact answer without the rest of the code but I would suggest using margin left to animate right as well.

```
$(".slide-right")
   .css("margin-left",0)
   .delay(400)
   .animate({
   marginLeft:$(this).width()
}, 900);
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JBgLc/1/

Answer (score 0):

`margin-right` only has an effect on elements surrounding or near `.slide-right`.  Basically, you wouldn't ***see*** what's going on unless you had other elements to the right of it. However, it is important to note that this will have no effect on `.slide-right` itself, just the surrounding elements. This can be better understood by looking at a demo with `display:inline;`:

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/74JtL/

A better way to go about this would be using `right` instead of `margin-right`, however, you would also need to use `position`:

```
$(function(){
    $(".slide-right")
   .css("right",$(this).width())
   .delay(400)
   .animate({
   right:0
}, 900);
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/74JtL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Using a negative `margin-right` often doesn't work -- it's better to use a positive `margin-left` instead because the `margin-right` only applies to objects following: it does not affect the location of the object it is assigned to.

Use:

```
.css("margin-left",$(this).width())
```

instead of:

```
.css("margin-right",-$(this).width())
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/x764M/).

Answer (score 0):

Because the code is somewhat general, yet there is a desire for a CSS animation solution, I attached the animation using a check box instead of jQuery. You can change the direction of the slide by adding a negative to the margin-left attribute in the keyframes. I only set this up for webkit, but it can easily be extended to other browsers.

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .slide-right{
-webkit-animation-delay:400ms;
-webkit-animation: slider 900ms; 
}

div{
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 border:1px solid black;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider{
 100%{margin-left:400px;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rfWtD/