# jQuery removeClass animation not working

Tags: jquery, animation, toggleclass

I'm having an onclick action to perform this function:

`$('#generalMenu').stop(true, true).toggleClass('slideLeft', 1000)`

and the `slideLeft` does slide when the `toggleClass` has `addClass` mode on it, but not on `removeClass` - how could I make it work for both?

Comment: `toggleClass` accept two parameters, class name and boolean to toggle it on and off. You are giving it numeric value of 1000 which is always true.

Comment: @TomMarulak then can you please show me how it would be done correctly?

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to do. Are you trying to toggle the class or animate the `#generalMenu`. Please create a demo so everyone can see what is not working. If you want to animate please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left

Answer (score 1):

I landed here because I couldn't get removeClass to animate.
As it is pointed out earlier, the addClass and removeClass does not accept a "duration" parameter. This is *only* possible, when jqueryUI is loaded.

Even though I had problems.

I solved mine by changing the css from:

```
.active { bottom: -150px; }
```

To:

```
.active { margin-top: 150px; }
```

After that, both the addClass and removeClass-methods was animating as excepted!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just:

```
$('#generalMenu').toggleClass('slideLeft', 1000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#generalMenu').toggleClass('slideLeft');
},1000)
```

or instead of an onclick function change your code to:

```
$('.element').click(function(){ 
   $('#generalMenu').toggleClass('slideLeft'); 
})
```

another way is using if/else conditionals:

```
$('.element').click(function(){ 
   if($('#generalMenu').hasClass('slideLeft')){
        $('#generalMenu').removeClass('slideLeft');
   } else {
      $('#generalMenu').addClass('slideLeft'); 
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: hmm might be the timing that's messing it up, you could try `.toggleClass('slideLeft')` and wrap it in a SetTimeout to create a delay. Do you need to set the 1 second delay for any reason?

Comment: why are you calling this toggle from an onclick action? could you change it to `$('.element').click(function(){ $('#generalMenu').toggleClass('slideLeft'); })`

Comment: hmm weird, something else must be breaking it when it tries to remove the class, you can do it with an if else conditional instead, not sure if that'll help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding transition-duration: 1000; to your css for #generalMenu.

```
#generalMenu { transition-duration: 1000; }
```