# jQuery Nav Menu sliding from left to right?

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to modify my code so that I can simply have my navigation menu slide from left to right instead from top to bottom and back up? If not, what would be a clean way to write the jquery code to have the menu slide in from left to right and back?

jQuery:

```
   $(".nav-dropdown-btn").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".nav-menu").css("display") == "none" ) {
        $(".nav-menu").slideDown();
    } else {
        $(".nav-menu").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no generic slide left or right animation, so you sort of have to create it yourself.  [Slide right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left)

You also might want to set `white-space:nowrap;` for each of the li elements though so you don't get a weird animation where it expands as the width shrinks.

```
$(".nav-dropdown-btn").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav-menu").animate({width:'toggle'}, 1050);
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YnwWNdxEUFupRIfgQteH?p=preview)