# how to toggle on div div out of two div inside another div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside a single div and I want to hide the left div on clicking button.I am trying but hiding is done on lower to upper side and i want toggling from right to left.can someone give me suggestion....
Here is my code..

```
.pg_bd {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table-caption;
}

.pg_bd_left_mod {
    width:240px;
    background-color:#7f7f7f;
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-left : 0.5%;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
}

.pg_bd_right_mod {
    width:85%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#7f7f7f;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Post your **enough CSS** and **HTML**, to get an answer. Also better if you could create a similar demo using **Snippet** or **[JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)**.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left