# smooth jquery tab sliding

Tags: jquery

Cannot figure out how to use the hide/show jquery
Whenever i pass through specifics it changes how the rest of the code works and displays all tabs on one page

```
 $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
       // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
       // which tab is active and its associated content
       var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

       // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
       // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
       $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
       $active.addClass('active');

       $content = $($active[0].hash);

       // Hide the remaining content
       $links.not($active).each(function () {
         $(this.hash).hide();
       });

       // Bind the click event handler
       $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
         // Make the old tab inactive.
         $active.removeClass('active');
         >trying to figure out how to change so that it will slide to new tab
         $content.hide();

         // Update the variables with the new link and content

         $active = $(this);
         $content = $(this.hash);

         // Make the tab active.
         >trying to figure out how to change so that it will slide to new tab
         $active.addClass('active');
         $content.show();

         // Prevent the anchor's default click action
         e.preventDefault();
       });
     });
```

Comment: You should create a jsfiddle or similar to illustrate your problem :-)

Comment: I'll try and figure that out and add it on here soon. My problem is that when I 'click' a different tab the page loads that tab quickly without animation. What I am looking to do is when I click one of the 3 tabs the tab slides out of the way-and the new one that is 'clicked' slides in from either the right or left side, whichever is closer on the nav menu

Comment: I think there isn't a native jQuery method to do that. Maybe this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left

Comment: However, you can use $.slideDown / Up , or fadeIn /out methods to get an smoothed animation instead of the instant hide/show methods.