# Replacing text with fade in and fade out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change "S3" text inside the header to "Standing Solid State" at the same time that the width of the nav-box slides.

I'd like to have the "S3" fade out when the width expands and have the "Standing Solid State" fade in during that time.

http://jsfiddle.net/5mL0bvxu/

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "noteCard-box">
    <!-- S3 NOTECARD -->
    <div id="s3">
        <div class = "s3-header">
            <h1 id="s3-abbrev">S3</h1>
        </div>

        <div id = "s3-detail" class = "noteCard-details">
            <p> S3 Notes go in this section would animate</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.noteCard-box{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 4px solid red;
}


.s3-header, .iam-header, .ebs-header{
    background-color: rgba(174, 214, 241, 0.5);
    display: flex, inline-flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 3em;
    width: 10%;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    border-left: 6px solid #48C9B0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 5px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-out;

}

.noteCard-details{
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex, inline-flex;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.33s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 6px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 35%;
}

.width-increase{
    width: 20%;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".s3-header").click(function(){
      $(".s3-header").toggleClass('width-increase')
    })
  });


$(document)
    $(".s3-header").click(function(){
      $("#s3-abbrev").animate({opacity:0},function(){
          $(this).text("new text").animate({opacity:1});  
      })
  });
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle was blank. FTFY. But also, what's the problem? What you described seems to be happening in the jsFiddle.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left) You don't want to animate the opacity, you want to animate the width.

Comment: @David Thanks for fixing that. I need it to transition to "Standing Solid State" when the tab is expanded and back to "S3" when it is collapsed.

Comment: @AdamH I need the text ("S3") to transition into "Standing Solid State". How can I achieve that by using slide?

Comment: Use 2 spans. One set to 0px width with the full text and one set to auto with the abbreviate. When they click immediately id the abbreviation and slide open the full text.

Comment: @AdamH sorry, I'm not sure where I would add that. I'm still very new to JS