# Slide Div Element from Right to Left when a Condition is True

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div element which is the `position:fixed`, `height:300px`, `width:200px` and `display:none`. And also I have a text field for filter data from database. When I click on one filtered data from the list, that data item is displayed on the text field. The data filtering process working fine but the problem is I want the div to slide from right to left when I clicked on filtered data item from the list and also I want that div to slide left to right after I deleted the item from the text field (empty field). Simply I want to slide a div from right to left and left to right based on a condition.

#### HTML

```html
<div id="search">
    <input type="text" name="searchData" id="searchData" class="searchData">
    <div class="show-data"></div> <!-- filter-data-list -->
</div>

<div id="div-slide" class="bg-light"></div> <!-- div-slide -->
```

#### CSS

```css
div#div-slide {
    height: 300px; 
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 10px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

#### JS

```js
$(document).on('click','li#show-list', function(){
$("#searchData").val($(this).text());
$(".show-data").fadeOut();

$("#div-slide").animate({
  width: "toggle"
});
});

 $(document).on('click','li#show-list', function(){
    $("#searchData").val("");
    $(".show-data").fadeOut();

    $("#div-slide").animate({
     width: "0"
   });
});
```

The `<li>` element is dynamically created in the db coding section and with my JS code, the `div` slides perfectly the first time I click on filtered data item, but when I click on second time it slides back to left to right (hides) because of `toggle`. I want the `div` to remain visible when an item display in text field and hide `div` when no data appears in text field.

Comment: please provide an example of your code please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slide right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I searched and searched but all examples are triggered with click event. what I need is to make the animation work for a condition.

Comment: any help please....!