# expand an element from right to left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to make a li element expand from right to left. I mean, if my element has the following css :

```
li{
   position:absolute
   left:10%;
   top:40px;
   width:100px;
}
```

how can I make that element top expand to the left with jquery, so that its top-right won't move, and it will be its left border that will move?

For now, I just have the following jquery, doing the same thing... from left to right:

```
$('li').animate({width:'+=100'},400);
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend setting your element's position using `top:` and `right:` rather than `top:` and `left:` in CSS, so when it grows the right side remains in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

there is a similar query on this that you can find here: [jQuery slide left and show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521291/jquery-slide-left-and-show/521468#521468)