# JQuery and <div> slide left

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link named 'changediv'. On the click of this link I want one div to slide out of the browser left and at the same time have a div slide left into the browser.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: **[jQuery slide left and show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521291/jquery-slide-left-and-show)**

Comment: At least show something that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like;

```
$('#changediv').click(
function() {
    $('#div1').animate({"width": 0}, "slow");
    $('#div2').animate({"margin-left": 0}, "slow");
});
```

Here is the working ***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xs2du/)***

or if your body (or parent div) has a fixed width, you  may try

```
$('#changediv').click(
function() {
    $('#div1').animate({"width": 0}, "slow");
    $('#div2').animate({"width": 400}, "slow");
}); //I used a width of 400px for testing
```

Here is the working ***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xs2du/1/)***

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can test this:

```
$('.changeDiv').on('click', function() {

  $('#div_one').animate({
     left: -9999
  },1000, function() {
     $('#div_two').animate({
        left: 200
     });
  });

});
```