# How can I use jQuery to create a left and right sliding effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have the following jQuery code snippet:

```
var target1 = $('.div1');
var target2 = $('.div2');
target1.delay(1500).fadeIn();
target2.delay(3000).fadeIn();
// I want to use slide left here instead of .fadeIn()
```

Similar to `.fadeIn()` is there a slide left/right option?

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521291/jquery-slide-left-and-show) but I'm not sure how to implement it or if it's the right one.

Comment: You can also look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left

Comment: Why not go for one of the thousands (free) plugins available?

Comment: Thanks but my code is a bit different so not sure how i can implement the toggle stuff into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the code from the link you posted.

Include the needed libraries (or use local copies):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>
```

Add this Javascript to your page:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  slideRightShow: function(speed) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, +speed || 1000);
    });
  },
  slideLeftHide: function(speed) {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, +speed || 1000);
    });
  },
  slideRightHide: function(speed) {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, +speed || 1000);
    });
  },
  slideLeftShow: function(speed) {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, +speed || 1000);
    });
  }
});
```

I even added the `speed` parameter so that you can specify how fast you want it to animate.

And from then on, you can use something like this:

```
$("#element_id").slideRightShow();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EzP2q/1/

Comment: Thanks @ian i tried using the solution above but it won't work.  I get the following error: ReferenceError: Query is not defined
Query.fn.extend({

Comment: I changed it by adding JQuery and it still gives me the same error but this time with JQuery rather than Query.

Comment: @user2184056 You didn't include the jQuery libraries like I said (the first thing in my answer). I updated my answer with a DEMO at the end, which works for me. I even changed the code so that you can specify how fast, if you wanted.

Comment: @ian i am using your code above and I am stuck.  How can i show test sentence by default and instead of the click button i want to add a next and previous button and use it display different slides.  Any help? I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644018/how-do-i-make-this-jquery-slider-render-slides-properly

Answer (score 2):

Here, check this out! This is what you need!

This tut explains everything you need -> [**Slide Elements in Different Directions**](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has a `slide` function

[Check out the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide)

Comment: Hi, but I am new to JS so unsure how I would implement it into my code?