# How do I make this JQuery slider render slides properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

Let me first begin by saying I am new to JQuery so I am guessing my way through this, which isn't ideal but I am going to invest more time learning stuff properly.

CODE:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.fn.extend({
  slideRightShow: function(speed) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, +speed || 1000);
    });
  },
  slideLeftHide: function(speed) {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, +speed || 1000);
    });
  },
  slideRightHide: function(speed) {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, +speed || 1000);
    });
  },
  slideLeftShow: function(speed) {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, +speed || 1000);
    });
  }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".left_hand_icon").on("click", function () {
        $("#slide1").slideLeftShow();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".right_hand_icon").on("click", function () {
        $("#slide2").slideRightShow();
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navigator">

<div class="left_hand_icon">Left</div>
<div class="right_hand_icon">Right</div>
</div>

<div id="slide1">Slide 1 content</div> <!-- displayed by default and i need to slide this away when the next slide is requested -->
<div id="slide2" style="display:none">Slide 2 content</div>
<div id="slide3" style="display:none">Slide 3 content</div>
<div id="slide4" style="display:none">Slide 4 content</div>
```

What I need help with?

Using my JS:

1)  how can i on clicking left_hand_icon or right_hand_icon make the current content slide away and then show the next one? I am using display:none; to hide them but then how do I hide the current one when it's being displayed.  Can you help me head in the right direction with this?

2)  When the page is loaded the first slide is showing.  How can I disable the ability for the user to click the left one since we are on the firs slide and how can I do the samething for the last slide where the next button shouldn't be able to be clicked since there is no slide to be shown?

Can you help me head in the right direction with this?

Comment: BTW, you have a typo on row 4 in your HTML (the right_hand_icon div is not closed, you're missing a `/` in `</div>`.

Comment: @emillundberg thanks for noticing.  i made the change in the question and in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part 1

You already have the `slideLeftHide` etc. functions up and running, so all you need to do is figure out a way to apply them. You could, for instance, add a `currentSlide` class to one of them and move that class around using the `next()` and `prev()` DOM traversal functions in jQuery. That would let you select the current slide with a selector like `$("#slides .currentSlide")` if you wrap all your slides in a `<div id="slides">`.

### Part 2

You could do this with [jQuery UI buttons](http://jqueryui.com/button/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".left_hand_icon").button().click(function () {
        $("#slide1").slideLeftShow();
    }).button("disable");
});
```

and then call `$(".left_hand_icon").button("enable")` when you want to re-enable it.

Here's a jsFiddle demonstrating the whole concept: http://jsfiddle.net/g5BA3/5/ - though the animation isn't particularly pretty.

Comment: Thanks Emil.  How do I make it go left if there is content to be seen and how do I stop it if there is no more content.  In the fiddle you provided, i wasn't able to see this.  Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, the script breaks down if you make the Hide/Show calls swap places.

Comment: You could check if the `.currentSlide` element is the first or last child of its parent, and do nothing if it is. You may also want to disable the buttons accordingly when you perform the animation and notice that the incoming element is the first/last one.

Comment: All of what you have said is foreign to me but i will do my best to do this.

Comment: thx exactly what i am looking for.  I a bit puzzled though.  How are you hdiing the rest of the slides when one is being displayed? i don't see display:none on those..

Comment: When I try to use this code on my site it doesn't work.  I get no error.  it won't work.  Besides the JQuery links do i need something else for this?

Comment: OK this is the error i get:  $(".left_hand_icon").button is not a function.  This is the complete line:
$(".left_hand_icon").button().click(function () {

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33459/discussion-between-kpo-and-emil-lundberg)

Comment: i managed to get it work but the problem is that i have many divs within divs and spans so the display:none is creating issues when a slide is shown..

Comment: How can I solve the rest of the problem? Under #slides i have other divs and spans and p tags.... the .currentslide doesn't get applied to all of them and therefore not all of the contents are being shown.  i need to submit this today so I am a bit nervous... can you help me figure out the rest? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve the first issue what you can do is:

- put all the image div elements in a parent container element, as in

> ```
> <div id="container">
>     <div id="slide1">Slide 1 content</div>
>     <div id="slide2" style="display:none">...
> </div>
> ```

- then you should apply CSS to parent container which will help you lay the given elements in proper inline manner and will form a long chain of images instead of showing one at a time.

**Note:** fix the width, height according to the image content, and set overflow to hidden so that rest of the images don't show up.

- next all you have to do is use the jQuery's [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method on click of your images (left & right) and shift the current div of [.active] div approporiately eg.

> ```
> ...
>     $('.active').animate({
>         left: '-280px';     //or the width + padding/margin of images.
>     });
> ```

Coming to the second  point, you can have a variable tht tracks the current object in focus (just the index) and if the index is equal to the number of 'div' elements present [$('div[id*="slide"]').length] you can disable the right button, and similarly left one for '0'th index.

Rough Fiddle for the same is : http://jsfiddle.net/vsyg8/3/

hope this helps, and correct me if I am going wrong anywhere.

Comment: can you create a fiddle example? i am a bit lost about this.  Thanks!

Comment: Here is the fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/vsyg8/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/vsyg8/3/) , its just a rough implementation of the above said concept, but I think will be helpful, and you can always tweak around.  Just fix the size of you text containing divs and this will be good to go.