# jQuery slide from right, change image then slide back

Tags: jquery, image, function, swap

I'm working on a script and I need an image with a fixed position to slide from right (it's not initially visible since I have the body overflow hidden) but still be in the right side, change the image after 3 seconds, keep that image for 1 second then change back to the initial image then slide back to right until it's not visible anymore. I need to do this every 1 minute. I've made this script, but it doesn't slide from right, it just appears there and when the images are switched there is a blank space for less than 1 second.

```
setInterval(
function(){
        $('#rgir').css('right', -80);
         setTimeout(function(){
        $('#rgir').html('<img src="images/blink.png" />');
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#rgir').html('<img src="images/normal.png" />');
        $('#rgir').css('right', -200);
    }, 1000);
    }, 3000);
setTimeout(function(){
    }, 20000);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if this code just sets it to appear at two different coordinates, you may need the slide functionality in jQuery UI for this one.

[jQuery slide left and show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521291/jquery-slide-left-and-show)