# Open Div from Left to Right onClick

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have HTML like:

```
a#clickme{width:20px; height:20px; background:#444; cursor:pointer;display:block; text-indent:-9999px}
div.mydiv{width:200px; height:200px;border:2px solid #666; position:fixed; left:-200px}

<a id='clickme' href='#'>Click Me</a>
<div class='mydiv'></div>
```

Now, I want use click on `clickme` to open `mydiv class` from left to right. and click again to close it.

How can I use Jquery to do that?

Comment: Have a look at the jquery docs (http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/). There is an example at the end

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521291/jquery-slide-left-and-show ... search is a great friend, eh?

Comment: @drkunibar:I want it like toggle but it slide from left to right only

Comment: @JeremyMiller For toggeling you can have a look at the jquery doc here: http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/ . You need to change the options for `fadeToggle` like you want

Comment: @drkunibar Yes, I know, but fading wasn't in the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can animate the 'left' attribute using jQuery:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    var $slider = $('.mydiv');
    $slider.animate({
       left: parseInt($slider.css('left'),10) == -200 ?
       0 : -200
    });
});
```

Alternatively, use outerWidth():

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    var $slider = $('.mydiv');
    $slider.animate({
       left: parseInt($slider.css('left'),10) == -$slider.outerWidth() ?
       0 : -$slider.outerWidth()
    });
});
```

Check out this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/58bBK/1/)

Comment: It is great but why couldn't I click it on second time?

Comment: I have updated the answer, check out the new demo :) - Michael Vangelovski