# how use nextbutton and prevbutton click move oneitem is left and right jquery i wanted slide item.. how use jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i want nextbutton click rightslide oneitem and prevbutton click leftslid onitem how use jquery ....
please help me... i am tired...

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
<div class="nextbutton">Next</div>
<div class="prevbutton">Prev</div>
```

//jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".prevbutton").click(function(){

        //how use one item
    });

    $(".nextbutton").click(function(){
        how use slide one item
    });

});
```

use jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/fj6z8/1/

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521291/jquery-slide-left-and-show

Comment: not sir, i not use plugin.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      check this js fiddle
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/fj6z8/6/**

```
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $(".prevbutton").click(function(){
                    $( ".items" ).scrollLeft( $( ".items" ).scrollLeft()-200 );
                    //how use one item
                });

                $(".nextbutton").click(function(){
                                $( ".items" ).scrollLeft( $( ".items" ).scrollLeft()+200 );
                });

        });
```

Comment: i want slide move effect

Answer (score 1):

here what you want:

```
$(".prevbutton").click(function(){
        $(".items").animate({scrollLeft: $( ".items" ).scrollLeft()-210},600);
});

$(".nextbutton").click(function(){
    $(".items").animate({scrollLeft: $( ".items" ).scrollLeft()+210},600);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raskalbass/fj6z8/9/)