# jquery slide function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make a page with slide but slide function doesn't work.

Code:

```
$("#left").click(function () {
      $("#bolge").show('slide', 'left', 1000);
      $("#main").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
      $('#main :input').attr('disabled', true);
      $x = 1;
});
```

I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: m.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Comment: [jQuery's documentation for `show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-easing-complete)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some issues.

From jQuery documentation:

```
.show( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

The **show** method only effects the visibilty.

If you're looking for some custom animation, you could use this solution:
[jQuery slide left and show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521291/jquery-slide-left-and-show)