# Show a hidden element and then animate it

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I make the hidden `form` animate from right to left, after the class `.button` is hidden. I can make something like that, but I cannot synchronize their animations. 
When the `button` is clicked, it goes to the right by some pixels and then is hidden, and before it gets hidden, I want the `form` to animate.

How can I create same effect like the form was inside `.button` class, and appears from there?

Any help very appreciated!

Here is the fiddle: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/w6cug6Lr/23/)

Comment: this can be your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521291/jquery-slide-left-and-show

Comment: refer this https://jsfiddle.net/KFmLv/6436/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
  $('a.button').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hidden-btn');
    $('.myform').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.myform input').focus();
  });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}
.button {
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 222px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 44px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.4s
}
.hidden-btn {
  left: 200%;
}
.myform {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: none;
    left: 50%;
    top: -145px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.myform input {
    float: left;
    width: 284px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 63px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    border: none;
    color: #767676;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: lighgrey;
}
.myform button {
     width: 170px;
    height: 44px;
    border: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: lighblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="button">Test</a>
  <form class="myform" action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <button type="submit">try</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But, I need the hidden element animation to start in the same position when button cliked is hidden on click

Comment: they have the same position now, I updated the answer .. just adjusted the `.myform { top: -145px;}` property

Answer (score 1):

try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shailesh87/a6vkuwej/) update
in this example we use `CSS3` animation.